# make a plot from an editable dataset rshiny rhandsontable

Tags: r, graph, shiny, rhandsontable

Is it possible to create a graph from an editable table ?
I have a table that I edit with rHandsontable and I would like to show on a tab a graph using my last edited data. Is there a way to do it ?

For example, lets say I have a : `mydata<-data.frame(num=seq(1,10), square=seq(1,10)^2)`

So far my code looks like that :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardSidebar( 
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Preview", tabName="previsualisation", icon=icon("table")),
      menuItem("Graphs", tabName="graphs", icon=icon("chart-bar"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "previsualisation", 
              basicPage(mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("preview")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "graphs") #where I would like the graph to appear
    )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  previous<-reactive({mydata}) 
  
  test_changes<- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$preview)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$preview)){
      mytable<-as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$preview))
      mytable<-mytable[1:nrow(mydata),]

      mytable[, "square"]<-mytable$num^2
      mytable
    }
  })
  
  output$preview <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(test_changes())})

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then if I modify a number of the `num` column, the `square` column is automatically modified.

Is there a way once this modifications done to generate a plot with x=num, y=square ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your example code doesn't work, `previous` and `precedent` are not defined

Comment: Indeed, it was a mistake. I edited it not it should work :)